# How to support memory for langChain agent OpenAIFunction type?

Tags: openai-api, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

`I want to use memory with langChain Agent type OpenAIFunction I have added the chat_history but still agent is not able to use previous conversation data.

This is my code

```py
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder,PromptTemplate
from langchain.agents import tool,initialize_agent,AgentType
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferWindowMemory,ConversationBufferMemory,ReadOnlySharedMemory

llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-4-1106-preview", temperature=0)


@tool
def getSquareOfNumber(number: str) -> str:
    """Metod used to return the square of the provided input."""
    print("Inside method getSquareOfNumber")
    x= int(number)*int(number)
    return "The square of "+ str(number)+" is " + str(x)


tools = [getSquareOfNumber]


promptString = """
            You are a very powerful assistant with access to chat history and can use tools when required.
            You don't know how to calculate the square of a number, so you'll use the getSquareOfNumber tool.
            Previous chat history consisting of messages between human and AI:
            {chat_history}
            
            Human : {input}
            AI:""
            {agent_scratchpad}
"""
prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(promptString)

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history")

agent = initialize_agent(tools=tools,
                         agent=AgentType.OPENAI_FUNCTIONS,
                         llm=llm, 
                         prompt=prompt,
                         memory=memory,
                         verbose=True,
                         )

user_input =""
while user_input != 'exit':
        user_input = input('Ask > ')
        if user_input != 'exit':
            response = agent.invoke({"input": user_input})
            print(response)`
```

`This are the example and working of above program` Ask > what is the square of numer 5

> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...

Invoking: `getSquareOfNumber` with `{'number': '5'}`

Inside method getSquareOfNumber
The square of 5 is 25The square of the number 5 is 25.

> Finished chain.
> {'input': 'what is the square of numer 5', 'chat_history': '', 'output': 'The square of the number 5 is 25.'}
> Ask > what is result of previous question

> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
> It seems there was no previous question provided in our conversation. If you have a question in mind, please feel free to ask, and I'll do my best to assist you!

> Finished chain.
> {'input': 'what is result of previous question', 'chat_history': 'Human: what is the square of numer 5\nAI: The square of the number 5 is 25.', 'output': "It seems there was no previous question provided in our conversation. If you have a question in mind, please feel free to ask, and I'll do my best to assist you!"}
> Ask >``

I am expecting that, agent to use the chat history provided and respond when user asks a question related to a previous conversations

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried using agent, but I have done it using ConversationalRetrivealChain function with ConversationalBufferMemory and OpenAI llm. Refer to this one ->
[Chat Retrieval](https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/chatbots#chat-retrieval)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for showing your interest, but I have a solution for it.

```
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.prompts import  MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain.schema import SystemMessage, AIMessage
from langchain.agents import OpenAIFunctionsAgent, AgentExecutor
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.agents import tool
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI
from langchain.schema import SystemMessage, AIMessage

import langchain 

    
langchain.debug = True

llm = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-4-1106-preview", temperature=0,verbose=True)

@tool
def getSquareOfNumber(number: str) -> str:
    """Method used to return the square of the provided input."""
    print("Inside method getSquareOfNumber")
    x = int(number) * int(number)
    return "The square of " + str(number) + " is " + str(x)

tools = [getSquareOfNumber]

chat_history = []

message = SystemMessage(
    content=(
        "You are very powerful assistant, you know to develop a taxanomy for a given input you use getTaxonomy method, you also don't know how to calculate square of a number so youi use method getSquareOfNumber"
        "you will be using the previous conversation history if the user/human ask question on previous convoersation."
    )
)

prompt = OpenAIFunctionsAgent.create_prompt(
    system_message=message,
    extra_prompt_messages=[MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history")],
)

agent = OpenAIFunctionsAgent(llm=llm, tools=tools, prompt=prompt)

agent_executor = AgentExecutor(
    agent=agent,
    tools=tools,
    verbose=True,
    return_intermediate_steps=True,
)

user_input = ""
while user_input != 'exit':
    user_input = input('Ask > ')
    if user_input != 'exit':
        # Invoke the agent and pass the current chat history
        response = agent_executor.invoke({"input": user_input, "chat_history": chat_history})
        base_message = AIMessage(content=response['output'])
        chat_history.append(base_message)
        print(AIMessage(content=response['output']))

Output Example:
Ask> my name is khwaja
'Hello Khwaja! How can I assist you today?'
Ask> what is my name?
'Your name is Khwaja, as you introduced yourself in the previous message. How can I help you further?'
```